# Angular error chunk asset optimization cleancss-webpack-plugin

Tags: angular, build, command-line-interface

I can `ng serve` and `ng build` just fine, however `ng build --prod` returns the error below.  I have tried to uninstall cleancss and reinstall.
These are my current version(s)

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.2
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.2
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.2
@angular/cli                      7.2.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.2
@schematics/angular               7.2.2
@schematics/update                0.12.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.2
webpack                           4.28.4

PS C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan> ng build --prod
 92% chunk asset optimization cleancss-webpack-pluginC:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\can-override.js:76
    return overrideCheckers[position](validator, value1, value2);
                                     ^

TypeError: overrideCheckers[position] is not a function
    at C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\can-override.js:76:38
    at everyValuesPair (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\every-values-pair.js:20:10)
    at overridable (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\merge-into-shorthands.js:154:10)
    at invalidateOrCompact (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\merge-into-shorthands.js:85:10)
    at mergeIntoShorthands (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\merge-into-shorthands.js:44:5)
    at optimizeProperties (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\properties\optimize.js:29:5)
    at recursivelyOptimizeProperties (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\optimize.js:63:9)
    at level2Optimize (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\optimizer\level-2\optimize.js:77:3)
    at optimize (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:147:5)
    at C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\clean.js:120:29
    at C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:26:64
    at loadOriginalSources (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\load-original-sources.js:26:5)
    at C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:26:14
    at applySourceMaps (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\apply-source-maps.js:34:5)
    at C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:25:12
    at fromStyles (C:\dev\cetevanV3\cetevan\node_modules\clean-css\lib\reader\read-sources.js:152:5)
```

Comment: found the problem.  after hours of checking my css I found what it did not like.  I think if they are going to place an error like this it should be more descriptive.